# Read multiple hash at a time and update the values in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, ruby-hash

Consider the variables:

```
ctr = ['cobol',nil,nil,'test',nil,'cobol', nil]

h1 = {
0=>{"ABC"=>"10000100126N", "CDE"=>"2013-08-30-}", "TPP"=>"11400000206633458812N", "APD"=> "01531915972", "PRODUCTID"=>"113n", "OPP"=>"201509n", "CTC"=>"C"}, 
1=>{"ABC"=>"00000039540A", "CDE"=>"0182.22X", "TPP"=>"1234.565N", "APD"=>"12345600", "PRODUCTID"=>"ACHN", "OPP"=>"00000000000119964.1256", "CTC"=>"00000000000211920"}
}

h2 = {'{' => '+0', 'A' => '+1', 'B' => '+2', '}' => '-0', 'N' => '-5'}
```

The task is to read the `ctr` data and where the value is `cobol`, we need to apply logic for those values in h1 hash only.

we need to parse the hash `h1` and if the last char in hash's value matches with one of the key in hash `h2` then replace that value with the corresponding value and prepend symbol to the string.

For example: when we scan hash `h1`, for value "10000100126N", as the last char is N and it exists in `h2`, then the output should be '-100001001265' where 5 is appended and - is prepended. [Not that the ctr for this is 'cobol']

But if we look at the second value "CDE"=>"2013-08-30-}", since for this key-value pair, the ctr value is not cobol, wee do nothing with the string.

This is what i have done so far:

```
h1.each do |k,h|
    h.update(h) do |*, v|
        # puts v
        h2.each do |q,p|
            if (v[-1] == q)
                v.sub!(v[-1], p[-1])
                 v.sub!(/(.*?)/, p[0] +'\1')
            end
        end
        v
    end
end
```

This code is updating the string as per the requirement, but its running for all the values in `h1`, i need to run the code only for the corresponding index where the value in the array `ctr` is 'cobol'

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @sawa - if the value in array `ctr` is 'cobol' then for the corresponding element's value (index wise) in hash `h1` needs to be converted.

for example index of cobol in array ctr is [0,5]

0 and 5 elements in hash `h1` are 'ABC' and 'OPP', the corresponding values in the hash should be updated as per the following logic:

if the last character of the values in hash `h1` exists in the hash h2, then replace it with corresponding key's value[last char] from hash `h2`

for example: 10000100126N should be changed to -100001001265

I need to achieve the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all a warning when you are matching `Hash` positions with `Array` indexes. In your example `['cobol',nil,nil,'test',nil,'cobol', nil]` correspond with the keys `["ABC", "CDE", "TPP", "APD", "PRODUCTID", "OPP", "CTC"]` from the inner `Hash` of `h1`. Keep in mind that a `Hash` is not index based but key based. This means, in theory the order of the hash is not maintained. A better way of doing it is by defining a `Hash`, like so: `{"ABC"=>"cobol", "CDE"=>nil, "TPP"=>nil, "APD"=>"test", "PRODUCTID"=>nil, "OPP"=>"cobol", "CTC"=>nil}`.

With this warning out of the way, let's get to the answer.

What you are looking for is the `Enumerable#zip` function, to combine every value with its corresponding value in `ctr`.

```
[:a, :b, :c].zip([1, 2, 3])
#=> [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]]
```

First we need to loop through your hash, you're using `Hash#each`. Since this is a transformation `Enumerable#map` is a better fit. The `map` functions results in a array with transformed values. The resulting array can be transformed back into a `Hash` with the correct structure.

```
[[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 3]].to_h
#=> {:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}
```

Here's the solution I came up with. It's not the most clean, but it works.

```
check_logic = lambda do |type, value|
  return value unless type == 'cobol'
  return value unless h2.has_key?(value[-1])
  "#{h2[value[-1]][0]}#{value[0...-1]}#{h2[value[-1]][-1]}"
end


result = h1.map { |k1, v1| [k1, v1.zip(ctr).map { |(k2, v2), type| [k2, check_logic.call(type, v2)] }.to_h] }.to_h
#=> {0=>{"ABC"=>"-100001001265", "CDE"=>"2013-08-30-}", "TPP"=>"11400000206633458812N", "APD"=>"01531915972", "PRODUCTID"=>"113n", "OPP"=>"201509n", "CTC"=>"C"}, 1=>{"ABC"=>"+000000395401", "CDE"=>"0182.22X", "TPP"=>"1234.565N", "APD"=>"12345600", "PRODUCTID"=>"ACHN", "OPP"=>"00000000000119964.1256", "CTC"=>"00000000000211920"}}
```

As you can see I'm using `zip` to combine each value of the `Hash` with the `ctr` `Array`. I'm also using mass assignment (don't know the correct term). A simple example of this is:

```
(v1, v2, v3) = [1, 2, 3]
```

Resulting in `v1` having value `1`, `v2` having value `2`. In the second `map` there are 2 params, the first is an `Array`, containing the key and value of the inner `Hash`, the second is the value from the combined `ctr` `Array`. By using mass assignment I can give the key and value their own variable name.

Since the logic is a bit to much for a one liner I moved it to a lambda, but this could also be a function (when passing h2 as param).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to match an array and a hash, which is just going to cause you problems.  It would be easier if you changed `ctr` to a hash as well:

```
ctr = {"ABC" => "cobol", "CDE" => nil, "TPP" => nil, "APD" => "test", "PRODUCTID" => nil, "OPP" => "cobol", "CTC" => nil}
```

Then at least you can match by keys.

Even better would be to start creating an object instead of using your hash.  Once you start nesting collection objects this deep, it's time to create some kind of object to make your life easier.

Comment: I forgot to mention objects. Nice to see them here.